# How to safely loop over a mutable array while modifying it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays

I have a `controller` which has an array holding `actors`. An actor is a object which will be called by the `controller`.

The problem: The `controller` iterates over the `actors` array and sends each actor an `-actionMessage`. The actor can create and register another actor with the `controller`, or remove an actor or even itself from the controller's actors array. It is routed through two methods:

```
-registerActor:(Actor*)actor;
-unregisterActor:(Actor*)actor;
```

**So while the controller iterates over the actors array, the list of actors can change.
Edit: And any newly added actor MUST go through the loop as well.**

What is best practice to deal with this problem? Should I create a copy of the actors array before iterating over it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a copy of your mutable array and iterate over that.

```
NSArray *loopArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: yourActorArray];
```

Or

```
NSArray *loopArray = [yourActorArray copy];
//in this case remember to release in nonARC environment
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this is the only really sane answer. The alternatives are mostly hacks (and some completely ignore that you can use `NS[Mutable]IndexSet` to remove items post-loop if that's the only modification occurring). It's not particularly pleasant, but it is the safest possible way to handle the situation.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect this: When an Actor is added, the loop must process it too. With the copy I would not process newly added actors. So then a Set is the better option to diff-out all those actors from the mutated array that are not in the processed set, and let the loop iterate over those too?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I usually do...

```
NSMutableArray *discardedItems = [NSMutableArray array];
SomeObjectClass *item;

for (item in originalArrayOfItems) {
    if ([item shouldBeDiscarded])
        [discardedItems addObject:item];
}

[originalArrayOfItems removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems];
```

hoping this helps.

Comment: Looks clever but it doesn't handle the case where during iteration additional elements are added to the array, and each of these elements must go though that loop.

Answer (score 2):

The standard procedure for enumerating through a mutable array that needs to be altered as you step through it is to make a copy and iterate through that, altering the original. I'm guessing the NSMutableArray of actors is a property belonging to your controller, and that registerActor: and unregisterActor: both alter this array. If you step through a copy you can remove actors from the original property through the methods without altering the copy.

```
NSMutableArray *actorArrayCopy = [self.actorArray copy];
for (id object in actorArrayCopy){
    //do stuff
}
```

In some cases, you can scrap fast enumeration and use a standard for loop, however, this is risky here. If objects are inserted or removed from the array, the indexes will shift (AFAIK), meaning you may end up skipping elements or going over an element multiple times.

Some people store elements to be altered (such as removed) in a separate array within the fast enumeration and perform all the changes at once once the enumeration is done, but you are using separate methods for adding and removing elements; the elements themselves determine what should happen and notify you. This would make things more complicated, so a copy will probably work best.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid making a copy of the array by doing this:

```
for(int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:i];

        i --;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a set instead of an array. Then you can copy the set, and after the operation is done, take a diff to see whats changed.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a macro called `smartFor` that allows you to do the same set up as a for-loop fast enumeration but handles modification of array. It takes advantage of a few C and CLANG exploits and is very simple and clean.

---

## Macro:

```
///Allows for modifying an array during virtual fast enumeration
#define smartFor(__objectDeclaration, __array, __block) {\
int __i = 0;\
while (__i < __array.count) {\
__objectDeclaration = __array[__i];\
NSObject *__object = __array[__i];\
[__block invoke];\
if ([__array indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:__object] != NSNotFound && ((int)[__array indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:__object]) <= __i) {\
__i = ((int)[__array indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:__object])+1;\
}\
}\
}
```

It automatically handles all of the [basic] wonky things you may do like adding objects (anywhere in the array, at any point during the "fast enumeration"<sup>[1]</sup>), removing objects, adjusting the index of objects, modifying objects, etc.

---

## Example Usage:

```
smartFor(NSNumber *aNumber, myArray, ^{
    if ([aNumber isEqualToNumber:@(3)]) {
        [myArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:aNumber];
    }
});
```

*<sup>[1]</sup>Note: It's not technically fast enumeration on a strict definition/performance basis, obviously, but behaves just like it for all intents and purposes*